# Update Specific Record Embedded In document

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

This is my first time using MongoDB and Spring-data-mongo.

There is a `Company` object

```
@Document
public class Company {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}

public class Vehicle {
    private String vehicleOwner;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String plateNumber;
    private Double speedLimit;
    private GeoJsonPoint currentLocation;
}
```

I would like to update `currentLocation` field for a vehicle with a given `plateNumber`

Obviousl, i'm stuck here

```
mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("vehicles"))), how to go to `plateNumber` field? And how to update `currentLocation` field for that particular matching `Vehicle` for the `Company`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, frame the query to fetch the required document and then create an Update object and populate values as shown below,

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("company_name")
               .and("vehicles")
               .elemMatch(Criteria.where("vehicleOwner").is("owner_name")));

Update update = new Update();
update.set("vehicles.$.plateNumber", "NEW NUMBER");

//You can use findAndModify or updateMulti based on your need.
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Company.class);
```

You can try the same for updating `currentLocation`.